# Echo a very large number

Tags: php

I have a unusual problem which I have no idea how to solve.

I have a JSON file, where a application id is stored, namely the following:

```
"app_id": "363924477024846"
```

I read my JSON file from the HDD and parse it with json_decode() to use it in my application.
However, at one point, I want to have the app-id sent to the browser. The problem is, if I echo that variable out, its printed as following:

```
2.7110712626725E+14
```

Is there any way to prevent this? I don't need it to be threated as a number by PHP since I am not doing any calculations with it - a string would be fine. But since its represented by numbers only, it seems that json_decode() threats it as a number, even tough I put quotes around it (which should indicate a string) or maybe PHP just does stupid type hinting in this case, I don't know...

Any ideas on how to handle that?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but what if you use `sprintf`, e.g. `$foo = sprintf("%d", $bar); echo $foo;`?

Comment: This is due to the limit of a 32bit signed integer.

Comment: @slugonamission: This would print "2147483647" on the screen with the app_id used above.

Comment: @ChristianEngel for some reason, I thought PHP had automatic bignum support. Nevermind.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same problem here: Simply use phps number_format function, which solves this issue:

```
$number = "363924477024846";
echo number_format($number, 0, '', '');

// 363924477024846
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks, man :)
I will accept your answer when I am able to in 9 minutes.

Comment: important to note that this doesn't work for large decimal numbers

Answer (score 5):

It looks like [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) has an option to treat big integers as strings.

```
json_decode($json, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)
```

Comment: This should be the answer, large integers may still be rounded on 32 bit systems.  This works when the accepted answer did not.

Answer (score 1):

try casting it to a string

```
echo((string)$theNumber);
```

Comment: try var_dumping the data and update your question with it please. That may help us out some

Comment: It looks like the problem arises at the time the value is decoded from the JSON string. That's when it's treated as an integer, so it's truncated to the max value for a 32-bit integer and after that, the original value can't be recovered.

Comment: var_dump the data you get from your file and var_dump the variable after json_decode

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution would be to add some character at the beginning or end of your number to force PHP to treat it as a string. Maybe intstead of "363924477024846" use "z363924477024846" and then remove the z when you need to use it. Obviously append this before you send it.

Comment: That came to my mind, too. But that would mean to have a "dirty" JSON file stored. Also, its very likely that someone who creates a new config JSON will forget about that in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the JSON file contents, have you tried wrapping the application ID in quotes, like so:

```
"app_id": "'363924477024846'"
```

As clentfort has said, you're exceeding the max value for a 32bit integer (~2.1bn signed)